# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el resultado de una consulta en Postgres a un archivo CSV?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Resulta que con cierta frecuencia debo extraer datos de PostgreSQL y tratarlos con una hoja de cálculo. Por ello, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de hacer una consulta `SELECT...` que guarde directamente a fichero, tal y como tiene MySQL con su `INTO OUTFILE ...`.

¿Hay alguna manera de guardar el resultado de una consulta directamente en un fichero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html) con esta sintaxis:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM bla) TO '/tmp/resultado.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';
--                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^
--                               fichero                         separador
```

Por ejemplo:

```
COPY (SELECT nombre, apellidos FROM usuarios) TO 'resultados.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no eres superusuario de la BD, puesdes utilizar \copy

```
\copy (SELECT nombre, apellidos FROM usuarios) TO 'resultados.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

Comment: esa es exactamente [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/211817/83)